# Prove that $T$ is a cyclic linear transformation iff any other linear transformations that commute with $T$ commute with each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$T$ cyclic meaning the vector space $V$ viewed as an $F[x]$-module is cyclic. One direction is clear since if $A$ and $B$ commute with $T$ then they are polynomials in $T$. In the other direction should I try to show that they are polynomials or directly that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is its characteristic polynomial?